# signing in with custom token doesn't pass the user details

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using `signInWithCustomToken()` after initiating it on the server.

```
async function signinWithToken(data, sendResponse) {
 const { token } = data;
 console.log(token);
 signInWithCustomToken(auth, token)
   .then((user) => {
    console.log(user);
    sendResponse({ success: true, user });
})
.catch((err) => {
  sendResponse({ success: false, message: err.message 
});
  
});
```

}

The problem is that the user object returned doesn't include the user details like displayName, email, etc...

[image]

Is there something I could do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom token only contains the properties/claims that you put into it. Firebase doesn't add any information to the custom token, so if you find certain values missing, it's because your code didn't add them while minting the token.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [minting a custom token using the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk).

Comment: When mint token with `nodejs`, can we assign a `displayName` or make `emailVerifed` to true? Use case for example I did auth with aws cognito and verified email and aws user has a username. I am trying to create a custom token through firebase function with aws information. But `createCustomToken` only accepts `uid` and `customClaim`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`signInWithCustomToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#signinwithcredential) method returns a Promise which resolves with a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential.md#usercredential_interface) and not a `User`.

So you need to do as follows:

```
async function signinWithToken(data, sendResponse) {
 const { token } = data;
 console.log(token);
 signInWithCustomToken(auth, token)
   .then((userCredential) => {
    console.log(userCredential.user);
    //..
})
```

Comment: Hmm.. Actually, it was a typo while writing the code. I am using onAuthStateChanged, so it returns the user automatically, and it doesn't show me the user's details, but when I do sign in without a token (Google provider), it returns the details finely. It is a weird thing

Comment: Please do not change your question to correct the typo: If other Stack Overflow users read this Q&A they might not understand it.

Comment: Okay. I changed it because it wasn't that wasn't the source of the issue as I am still getting no email & displayName